# Why is there no output in the given PHP file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to calculate ( by a PHP file ) the diameter, area and circumference of a circle whose radius is given by the user in a html file. User gives the values of the radius and PHP script calculates the above mentioned quantities. The problem is that when I am executing the program, the html takes the input but the PHP script isn't showing the output.

The code is as follows:-

**circle.html:-**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Circle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form method="GET" action="circle1.php">
    <center>
    <h1>Circle</h1>
    <table border= 2 width=200>
      <tr align=center>
        <td>Radius</td>
        <td><input type="text" name=radius size=5></td>
      </tr>
      <tr align=center>
        <td colspan=2>
          <input type="submit">
          <input type="reset">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**circle1.php:-**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Circle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
     <h1>Circle</h1>
     <?php
        define("PI",3.14159,TRUE);
        GLOBAL $d,$c,$a,$r;
        $r=$_GET['radius'];
        $d=2*$r;
        $c=2*PI*$r;
        $a=PI*$r*$r;
     ?>
     <table border = 2 width=200>
        <tr>
           <td>Diameter</td>
           <td><?php echo $d; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Circumference</td>
           <td><?php echo $c; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Area</td>
           <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <a href="circle.html"><h2>Back</h2></a>
     </center>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

sorry for such a long post. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try doing a `var_dump($_GET);` in your PHP file and see what's coming across.

Comment: What output are you getting? A blank screen? Or the HTML with nothing in it?

Comment: you have a few extra spaces `border = 2`, this should be `border=2` or ultimately `border="2"`

Comment: Is PHP's error reporting enabled? If you're getting a completely blank page, the odds are PHP is throwing an error but not reporting it because the config is telling it not to. Switch on the error_reporting flag to see what the error is; that should give you more info on what the problem is.

Comment: @andrewsi I am getting an HTML with nothing in it. I get the cells having "diameter","area","circumference" written in them but no numbers in the corresponding cells.

Comment: in circle1.php -- where are you opening <form> tag

Comment: The comments about the space are silly. That's not the problem. Do you get a totally blank page? If you view-source is there any output at all?

Comment: When you arrive at circle1.php, View the Source of your page. Under "Area", does it say `<td>Area</td><td></td>` or `<td>Area</td><td><?php echo $a; ?></td> `

If you see the `<?php` tags, then you have a problem with your Server.

Comment: @suresh.g - the form is in circle.html and it sends the data to circle1.php

Answer (score 1):

Some server setups such as various Amazon Linux AMIs require you to output HTML through php print functions such as echo to properly execute. If you have this type of setup, then you'll need to execute your **server-side** PHP code before you output all your **client-side** HTML.

Try this for **circle1.php**:

```
<?php
    define("PI",3.14159,TRUE);
    GLOBAL $d,$c,$a,$r;
    $r=$_GET['radius'];
    $d=2*$r;
    $c=2*PI*$r;
    $a=PI*$r*$r;
echo'
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Circle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
     <h1>Circle</h1>
     <table border="2" width="200">
        <tr>
           <td>Diameter</td>
           <td>'.$d.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Circumference</td>
           <td>'.$c.'</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
           <td>Area</td>
           <td>'.$a.'</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <a href="circle.html"><h2>Back</h2></a>
     </center>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>';
 ?>
```

Comment: This just isn't the problem. The code basically works, it's more of a server setup problem. Cut and paste it, it works. It's not a formatting question.

Comment: @Peter clearly his formatting is not optimized for any server setup. Attempting to resolve his issues with cleaning things up does not warrant a vote down.

Comment: It's not an answer to his question and doesn't help resolve his question. He's not asking about cleanliness of code. The only result of your answer is having him spend time fixing things that won't handle what he's trying to sort out.

Comment: @Peter If you read his question, it said "What's going on?". Some server setups such as various Amazon Linux AMIs require you to output HTML through php print functions such as echo to properly execute. This = fix to such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be cleaned up a bit, but it should work. There isn't anything intrinsically wrong with it. I literally cut and pasted it as a test and it works fine.

If the first page (pure HTML) works, but you get nothing for the second (circle1.php) then the first thing to check is if your webserver is configured to use PHP and if the path to the `php.ini` is accurate because the bottom line is that your PHP parser is out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You must have some problem related to `php.ini` or `apache` . Check weather your `<?php` code is escaping or not by checking source code. . If it is , put this code on the top  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try to debug it.

Answer (score -3):

You need to encapsulate your input properties with quotes.

Replace

```
<input type="text" name=radius size=5>
```

With

```
<input type="text" name="radius" size="5">
```

Comment: is this really necessary because I don't think that the error is due to this.

Comment: While you should do this as good coding practice, it has nothing to do with the issue he has.